# Read a variable in another thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

I'm using linux and I have two variable that is read/write in another thread. Once in a while (100ms) ThreadB reads the status of the variables and does something. It's basically a `while(1){ dosomething(); usleep(); }`. I'm worried the variables will be cached and never updated.

What's the best way to ensure the loop will work after optimizations? I am thinking `volatile` should do the job but I hear it doesn't work sometimes. Both loops don't run frequently (10ms+). What's the most simple and straightforward way to access them? I'm using C++11

I'm a little unsure how to use `std::atomic<int>`. Can I just use it like a normal int variable and it will work as expected?

Comment: Well you are right about `volatile`..

Comment: Anyone have a SO link with details about when volatile fails?

Comment: @donjuedo: IIRC it is because variables may be read/written in different order than specified causing weird results. In my case it's just fine but I rather know the proper way and refresh my memory on atomic

Comment: @donjuedo: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed just declare it as `std::atomic<int>`, and things should work as you want.

`volatile` is about preserving the sequence of addresses and values that the generated code must present to the processor for reading/writing. It doesn't at all constrain what the hardware does with that for purposes of **memory consistency**, which is the concern of `atomic`. Here's an [article from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming) explaining this difference.

The C and C++ standards (from 2011 onwards) define a *memory model* that describes what operations are or aren't defined according to the language, and what values an expression can produce if the program as a whole is well-defined.

According to the standards, any program doing unsynchronized access by multiple threads to a single object (e.g. your shared `int`), in which at least once access is a write, is *undefined*. Declaring a variable `volatile` doesn't make accesses to it synchronized. Accesses to variables declared as `atomic` are always synchronized, by definition.

In the default case, if you just use `atomic<int>` without changing anything else about how you use it, you'll get what are known as *sequentially consistent* accesses, which are the most strongly coordinated between threads, and hence potentially most costly. For your use case, that doesn't seem to be a concern - the cost is on the order of nanoseconds to microseconds, while you're polling in milliseconds. If you did need to optimize further, you could potentially specify less restrictive accesses.

Comment: IMO using anything but sequentially consistency is likely premature optimization. It's been a long time since I looked at this (probably in 2011) thanks for refreshing my memory. I was a little sad not to see a similar question on google/SO. Great answer

Comment: I only mentioned the existence of the alternatives for the sake of comprehensiveness, considering other future readers beyond the OP.